# 'Is not a symbol' error with collection radio buttons ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on quiz app, and I can't use `collection_radio_buttons` for answer choices. I have a tests table.

```
`Question = test.question`, `choice A = test.answerA` and so on.

<%=
collection_radio_buttons(:test, test[:id], Test.all, :id, [[test.answerA], [test.answerB], [test.answerC], [test.answerD]], {})
%>
```

But this is giving me an error:

> [["A) rasmiy"], ["B) ilmiy"], ["C) so'zlashuv"], ["D) badiiy"]]` *is
>   not a symbol*

Why is this happening?

Comment: try this: ` collection_radio_buttons(:test, :test_id, Test.all, :id, [test.answerA, test.answerB, test.answerC, test.answerD], {})`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, Marc-Alexandre Berube. :((( Error is staying the same as is!

Answer (score 0):

The fifth argument for `collection_radio_buttons` is the `text_method` that is to be called on your collection. You are passing an array through this argument instead. The error message `... is not a symbol` is telling you that the value that you're passing through that argument is an array, but it's expecting a symbol.

The method definition for `collection_radio_buttons` is:

```
collection_radio_buttons(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

You probably want something like:

```
<%= collection_radio_buttons(:test, test_id, Test.all, :id, :name) %>
```

... where `id` and `name` are callable attributes on instances of whatever comes out of `Test.all`.

Source: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons

Comment: That array is my answer options, how can I pass them? Or isn't it possible?

Comment: Pass your collection of options through the third parameter, `collection`, which is where you currently have `Test.all`. Have you read the docs?